# What is the English expression for "golden nest"?

Tags: expressions, terminology

> A person who is in a **golden nest** would not have freedom. They are living under someone's/others' command, although they live with privileges.

What is the English expression of **golden nest**? I am translating directly from my native language.

Could it be referenced to **golden handcuffs** as a metaphor?

Comment: Source please...

Answer (score 5):

I think you are referring to the metaphors: golden cage or [gilded cage](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gilded-cage?jss=0). Something that symbolizes material wealth but causes limited movement. Luxurious living but no freedom.

[*Golden handcuffs*](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/goldenhandcuffs.asp) is related to good compensation and benefits for a job, which makes it difficult for an employee to transfer to another work/company. (retention)

You may want to add the source where you encountered the term, so we may be able to give a better answer.